# What should a stratum server do with "mining.submit"?

Tags: json-rpc, development, stratum

I write some stratum server, for mining in the pool. The answer goes from the client to my server:

> `{"method": "mining.submit", "params": ["g", "06a8", "01", "1d025f83",
>   "c03f38ac"], "id":4}`

What should I do with this in my stratum server? What next do I need to do with this data?
(I write in Plain C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the documentation please: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum_mining_protocol#mining.submit

A quote from it:

> mining.submit
>
> `mining.submit("username", "job id", "ExtraNonce2", "nTime", "nOnce")`
>
> Miners submit shares using the method "mining.submit". Client submissions contain:
>
> Worker Name.
>   Job ID.
>   ExtraNonce2.
>   nTime.
>   nOnce.
>
> Server response is result: true for accepted, false for rejected (or you may get an error with more details).

2. You write:

   > What next do I need to do with this data?

You could check the poolserver for example code: https://github.com/GOSTSec/poolserver/blob/master/src/server/poolserver/Stratum/Client.h#L82

Comment: I know about `mining.submit("username", "job id", "ExtraNonce2", "nTime", "nOnce")`
Thanks for example. I watch it later.